# How do I change the vulnerable dependency of a non-vulnerable module in npm?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

**How do I force babel-core (and other dependencies) to use the non-vulnerable versions of the modules that I installed? npm version 6.14.6**

`"babel-core": {"version": "6.26.3","resolved": "some-resolved-registry","integrity": "sha-some-integrity==","requires": {"convert-source-map": "^1.5.1","debug": "^2.6.9","json5": "^0.5.1","lodash": "^4.17.4","minimatch": "^3.0.4","path-is-absolute": "^1.0.1","private": "^0.1.8","slash": "^1.0.0","source-map": "^0.5.7"},}`

I put my code up for a Vulnerability Scan, which told me to update lots of modules, and I did with the following script:
**npm install package@version-number**.

I did an **npm install**, and that generated the **package-lock.json** file, which now has the correct version of the module. However, when I put the code up for another vulnerability scan, the same module list came back, because non-vulnerable dependencies are using vulnerable dependencies in their package.json. **For example, I had updated lodash to 4.17.21 (non-vulnerable) but the Vulnerability scan showed that I was still using lodash 4.17.11 (vulnerable) because babel-core 6.26.3 (non-vulnerable) was using lodash 4.17.11**.